# Using amazon s3, upload files using their servers but URL should appear to be from mine

Tags: amazon-s3

Is it possible to upload files to amazon S3, using their servers (i.e. my server shouldn't be used in the upload process)?

I also want the URL to appear to be uploading to my server, is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look [here](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/VirtualHosting.html#VirtualHostingCustomURLs) for instructions on how to setup your CNAME record so that one of your subdomains can be an alias for an Amazon S3 bucket.

*Depending on your needs, you might not want "s3.amazonaws.com" to appear on your web site or service. For example, if you host your web site's images on Amazon S3, you might prefer http://images.johnsmith.net/ to http://johnsmith-images.s3.amazonaws.com/*

Comment: No I want the form URL to appear to be from my server.