# Amazon S3 - direct upload, hide action URL that user can't see it

Tags: forms, file-upload, amazon-s3, hide

We use Amazon S3 for storing large files, so we use direct upload from user's browser as described here: http://aws.amazon.com/articles/1434

My question is:
could I somehow hide form's action URL so user won't be able to find out where the file is being uploaded? Would it be 100% hiden or could I just at least make it harder for experienced users to find it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you need to give the information to the user so that they can use it to upload to S3... the only way to hide it would be to have them POST to your server, where you then re-POST it to S3, but that defeats the purpose doesn't it?

What's the concern, exactly? The document you linked shows that you have to sign everything so they know that only you could've made that form... so it's not like anybody can get at your data, anyway.

Comment: Thanks for quick replay. The purpose is that our bussiness know how is how to store large files, but wo don't want to let other users know where exactly those files are saved. Unfortunatly, right now, the solution with uploading to our server isn't possible due to high data traffic. So we want to upload it directly from user to Amazon S3. Is it possible to somehow overwrite the URL address so in the source code the form will have action with URL of our server but in reality it will point to Amazon? Thanks.

Comment: Well, no... because the source code (really, markup) is provided to the client in order for the client to act on it. Even if it were somehow obfuscated, the user still needs to know the address in order to use the address.

If this is security-motivated, it's not the way to do it. If this is pride-motivated (don't want to be seen using out-of-house infrastructure), lots of companies use S3 for exactly this sort of thing. If this is for some other reason, there's probably a better solution. What are you trying to accomplish by this?

Comment: Well we don't need to hide the form's action URL (there could be my server's URL), but we can't show the Amazon's URL. I just ran into this solution, could it work? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/717663/using-amazon-s3-upload-files-using-their-servers-but-url-should-appear-to-be-fr

Comment: That could work if you're trying to make the URL look nicer, but it doesn't change anything but the host part of the URL. And anyone so inclined could still check the domain name and find that it points to S3. If this is for security purposes, it won't work.

Comment: Ok, thank you for this consultation. No, it's not for security purposes. It's just for trying to hide our backend, that's all.

Answer (score 0):

You can't hide it since the whole point is going from their computer directly to s3, the fastest way possible.  Even if you removed it from the code and had your form submit button request a url to use, then hide, it will just be in console.log's network activity.  If you have to use s3, you maybe should install a faster uploader(or write one in c? haha) than node if you want to run it through your server.  which begs the question, what language/framework can upload to s3 the fastest?